# bindToController Angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.6

I have an issue with my directive after migration to lastest angular.

```
.directive('documentGrid',
    function() {
        return{
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                documentData: '=',
                remove: '&',
                edit: '&',
                documentDatasources: '='
            },
            controller: 'DocumentCrtl',
            controllerAs: 'vmDocument',
            //bindToController: true,
            //transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/Custom/Document/document.cshtml'
        };
    });

<div class="box" document-grid document-data="widget"
                             document-datasources="vm.datasource.data"
                             remove="vm.remove(item)"
                             edit="vm.openSettings(item,datasources)">
                        </div>
```

before move to lastest version it works fine with bind controller set to true but now it does't work. So I remove the bindToController : true and I need to use $scope to access to my varibile bind from html directive

I read guide, post and tutorial about directive but I don't find any solution.

Comment: I'm working with Angular 1.6 and `bindToController` on every `component` or `directive` and did not encounter any issues. Are you getting any error message in the console?

Comment: what is the error or issue?

Comment: i don't have a console error but if I write vmDocument.documentData (with bindToController = true) is undefined but if I write $scope.documentData is my object bind from call stack

Comment: vm != vmDocument

Comment: ok. So when I put my directive on page use code like ...                             document-datasources="vm.datasource.data". I suppose that in my controller bind to my directive I can access to documentDatasources via vmDocument.documentDatasources?

Comment: You should use the same name in html and js. If you define your controller controllerAs: 'vmDocument', in html you need to use vmDocument (not vm).

Comment: ok but in my controller how can access to varibile bind from main scope. The html is not the directive template definition but the code in main page where call and pass data to my directive

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace with this:

```
directive('documentGrid',
    function() {
        return{
            restrict: 'EA',
            bindToController: {
                documentData: '=',
                remove: '&',
                edit: '&',
                documentDatasources: '='
            },
            controller: 'DocumentCrtl',
            controllerAs: 'vmDocument',
            scope: {},
            //transclude: true,
            templateUrl: '/Custom/Document/document.cshtml'
        };
    });
```

Note that I changed `bindToController` and `scope`.

Then in your controller your must bind `this`, e.g.: `var vm = this;` at the first line of your controller preferably.

Finally you will be able to access your data in controller like this:

```
vm.documentData
```

See this fiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/2n5skwqj/794/](https://jsfiddle.net/2n5skwqj/1577/)
In the controller function I log the name.

Comment: The fiddle uses Angular 1.4.3 so may not be a valid test.

Comment: So this didn't work for me unless I injected `$scope` into my named controller (`this` was just an empty controller with no passed-in data) and also set the `scope` properties to be the same as the `bindToController` properties in the controller definition. It seems that in the directive definition: 1) `scope` is handling the data passed to the directive; 2) `bindToController` handles passing the `scope` data to the controller; 3) `controllerAs` determines how the scope data is made accessible to the template.